# SQL Rounding to nearest between 2 numbers

Tags: sql

Example

Value entered by the user :`34,26` (a+)

Values in the table:

```
34,14........A+    
34,42........A++    
34,52........A++
.
.
.
```

The value entered by the user is between `a+` and `a++`. In order to find the value of user, take the average of the closest upper and closest lower value, rounding up to the upper value if the value entered by the user is greater than the average, if the value entered by the user is lower than the average. Can you help with the sql query that will round to the lower value?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle Database? I removed the conflicting tags. Please only tag the one you're really using. (Note that the [tag:oracle] tag is for questions about Oracle Database, not any odd product by the company Oracle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do that; as far as I understood, you want to find value (stored in the table) which is the closest to value you enter as a "parameter".  If that's so, Oracle-based example (you originally tagged the question as such).

With sample data:

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> select * from test;

       COL
----------
     34,14
     34,42
     34,52
```

Query:

```
SQL> with
  2  minimax as
  3    -- find values in the TEST table that represent boundaries around entered value
  4    (select (select max(t.col) from test t where &&val >= t.col) mincol,
  5            (select min(t.col) from test t where &&val <= t.col) maxcol,
  6            (select max(t.col) from test t) maxx,
  7            (select min(t.col) from test t) minn,
  8            v.val
  9     from dual v
 10    )
 11    -- return the closest boundary
 12  select
 13    case when mincol is null then minn
 14         when maxcol is null then maxx
 15         when abs(&&val - mincol) < abs(&&val - maxcol) then mincol
 16         else maxcol
 17    end as result
 18  from minimax;
Enter value for val: 34.26

    RESULT
----------
     34,14
```

Some more testing:

```
SQL> undefine val
SQL> /
Enter value for val: 31

    RESULT
----------
     34,14

SQL> undefine val
SQL> /
Enter value for val: 36

    RESULT
----------
     34,52

SQL> undefine val
SQL> /
Enter value for val: 34.42

    RESULT
----------
     34,42

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) , but I have a question  (.........  v.val    from dual v) what exatctly v stands for ?

Comment: You're welcome. `v` is just a `dual` table's **alias**.